# Whats the different in coursework and research?

Tags: masters

I heard there are coursework and research for taking Master but are there any different?

Isn't both of them are about making research papers?

Comment: Masters degrees in what country?

Comment: In Malaysia, although I don't think there are any different.

Comment: Hope [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/44035/546) is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

With a course there is a teacher that teaches you specific topics. You may need that to write a research paper, and the teacher may test your knowledge by letting you do or simulate a research project, but that is secondary. In a course there is a teacher that guides your learning process, and the learning goal is typically more limited.

A research project is more open ended, there is typically a faculty member that coaches you through the process, but now you are the primary actor.